# Prepared statement in if else

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm trying to use prepared statement in if else. Sadly I'm getting Index 1 is out of range.
Added some details...
My code:

```
try {
        String query = "select * from dbo.Table";
        String width = jFormattedTextField1.getText();
        String heigth = jFormattedTextField2.getText();
        PreparedStatement ps;

        if (width.equals("") && heigth.equals("")) {
            query = "select * from dbo.Table ";
        } else if (width != null && !"".equals(width) && heigth != null && !"".equals(heigth)) {
            query += "where width = ? and heigth = ?";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, width);
            ps.setString(2, heigth);
        } else if (width != null && heigth.equals("")){
            query += "where width = " + width;
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        } else {
        query += "where heigth = " + heigth;
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    }
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I missed +

Comment: Why is this tagged sql-server?  PreparedStatement is Oracle.

Comment: @paparazzo Agreed, but note that `PreparedStatement` is a class from `javax.sql`, it has nothing to do with Oracle DBMS. It's just a class for handling prepared statements, regardless of the DBMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are supposed to create the `PreparedStatement` after you initialize the SQL `String`, which means it must be done inside the if-else body.

```
        String width = jFormattedTextField1.getText();
        String heigth = jFormattedTextField2.getText();
        PreparedStatement ps;
        if (width.equals("") && heigth.equals("")) {
            query = "select * from dbo.Table ";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        } else if (width != null && !"".equals(width) && heigth != null && !"".equals(heigth)) {
            query = "select * from dbo.Table where width = ? and heigth = ?";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, width);
            ps.setString(2, heigth);
        }
```

You should also initialize the `PreparedStatement` in an `else` clause, to make sure that it's initialized before you execute it.

EDIT:

Seeing your updated code, you are misusing `PreparedStatement` in the final two cases. I suggest:

```
try {
    String query = "select * from dbo.Table";
    String width = jFormattedTextField1.getText();
    String height = jFormattedTextField2.getText();
    PreparedStatement ps;

    if (width.equals("") && height.equals("")) {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    } else if (width != null && !"".equals(width) && height != null && !"".equals(height)) {
        query += " where width = ? and height = ?";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, width);
        ps.setString(2, height);
    } else if (width != null && height.equals("")){
        query += " where width = ?";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, width);

    } else {
        query += " where height = ?";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, height);
    }
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Nice but now I'm getting "The value is not set for the parameter 1" error

Comment: @n0rek That doesn't make sense, since you are setting parameter 1 immediately after creating the PreparedStatement (at least in my answer). Perhaps you have other code where you create a PreparedStatement with parameters and don't set them.

Comment: @n0rek you didn't show where `query` is declared. Perhaps it has a previous value (with parameters) when you concatenate to it the parameter-less query (in `query += "select * from dbo.Table ";`). I suggest you don't use concatenation.

Comment: I edited my question and updated whole code that is used under jButtonActionPerformed.

Comment: @n0rek you have an extra `ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);` after the if-else-if statement. Remove it.

Comment: You initialized ps variable after ps.setString is that correct? Also now it's throwing error: variable ps might not have been initialized
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

Comment: @n0rek oops, I misplaced it. fixed now. Also note that I added `ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);` to the first branch of the if statement.

Comment: Yeah that ps = conn.prepareStatement(query); did the job, thank you very much. Could you please tell me how to mark code in comments like you did?

Comment: @n0rek just surround it with since quotes `       `